# Does Microsoft Cluster Service (MSCS) Support Single-System-Image?

Tags: windows-cluster

Was wondering if using Microsoft Cluster Service with two Windows Servers will appear as using a single system with combined processing power?

Searched around but found multiple threads on Linux-based systems using OpenSSI or other Single-System-Image (SSI) cluster options, nothing discussing MSCS or any other Windows Based SSI.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MSCS isn't an HPC cluster. It's a highly available "failover" cluster that operates in an active / passive capacity.

However, Microsoft offers NLB (Network Load Balancer) to load balance front-end applications (such as web pages via IIS) in an active / active cluster. CLB (Component Load Balancer) can do the same with applications depending on whether the application is written to be clustered and / or how it stores its data.

I can get more specific, but I would need to know what workload you're looking to cluster and what version of Windows you're planning to use.

It's worth noting that what I describe above is NOT like OpenSSI. These are individual nodes with independent systems doing the work that are unified by a cluster resource manager. This is more common in modern systems, as we generally don't want to have to worry about the integrity of a simultaneously accessed machine image rather than several independent nodes that can be unified with a CRM and consistently configured with a CM product like SaltStack.